# Using Python (Selenium) to read, save, and then input a value from Web Page

Tags: python, selenium

We are pretty new to using Python and Selenium. So please bear with us. As part of our effort on test automation for our website, we have used a helper class to show the Captcha used during new customer registration (works great). We are now trying to read that value, save it to memory (a string) and then input that saved value in the  correct page element. This is something entirely new for us and we're at a loss. Here is what we have so far.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import unittest, time, re
import urllib, urllib2

class NewAccountTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        self.base_url = "http://www.test.com/"
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.accept_next_alert = True
        response = urllib.urlopen("http://www.test.com/")
        htmlSource = sock.read(id = "captcha")
        var.captcha = "htmlSource"
        sock.close()

#SIGN UP NEW USER

    def test_00_sign_up(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get(self.base_url + "/")
        driver.find_element_by_id("name").send_keys("Foo")
        driver.find_element_by_id("email").send_keys("test@me.com")
        driver.find_element_by_id("screenname").send_keys("1234")
        driver.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys("xxx")
        driver.find_element_by_id("password2").send_keys("xxx")
        driver.find_element_by_id("option1").click()
        driver.find_element_by_id("option2").click()
        driver.find_element_by_id("captcha").click()
        >> I don't how to send the var string to the element "captcha"
        driver.find_element_by_id("registration_button").click()
```

I am certain someone knows this all too easily, so any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Marcin it's hidden in the code :)

Comment: What exactly are you attempting to send to the "captcha" element? Is it a variable? From where?

Comment: I am trying to find out how to send `var.captcha = "htmlSource"`. Yes, from the `def setup(self)`. I didn't think just using the `.send_keys` would work here.

Comment: It should do :) Let us know if it doesn't!

Comment: Nope. I get: `TypeError: read() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'` Looking at the arguments, this should be ok?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use [send_keys()](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html?highlight=send_keys#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.send_keys):

> send_keys(*value)
>
> Simulates typing into the element.

```
driver.find_element_by_id("captcha").send_keys("test")
```

Comment: Really? All the rest of the code is accurate then? If I do that though, it will just send T E S T to the page element.

Comment: @Marcin You are amazingly helpful. Please go 'help' someone else.